# Changing an operator using drop down box to manipulate an input box

Tags: javascript, html, operators, calculator

I've just recently started learning JavaScript and I'm not sure how to go about allowing the user to select to calculate with a percentage or just a normal integer.

```
    <div id="pensionRev"  style="display:none; margin: 0 auto; width:600px;" class="answer_list" >
        <h3><u>Your pension will come to &pound;<span id="pensionfinal"></span></u></h3>
        <h3>If you contribute an additional
            <select name="operate" style="width:59px; text-align:left; font-size:17px;">
                <option value="pound" id="percentage">&pound;</option>
                <option value="percentage" id="percentage">%</option>
            </select>
            <div class="inpt" id="smallnum">
                <input class="input-xxsmall" id="incCont"
                       name="incCont" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="?">
            </div>
            a month
        </h3>
        <h3>Your pot will be.....
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Submit" type="submit">

        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="pensionRev2" style="display:none;  margin: 0 auto;  width:600px; border-radius:20px; border-bottom:ridge black 5px;" class="answer_list" >
        <h2 style="text-decoration:underline;">&pound;<span id="pensionfinal2"></span>!</h2>
        This is an increase of &pound;<span id="increase"></span></h3>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="/_/js/java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The program first takes age, percentage contribution etc then outputs the number and then shows if you add a certain amount of pounds (I'm trying to allow it to give you the options between pounds and percentage.

**Here's my JavaScript so far:**

```
    $salary = $("#salary");
    $eepension = $("#eecontrib");
    $pension_cont = $("#pension_cont");
    $ret_age = $("#ret_age");
    $DOB = $("#DOB");
    $employerCont = $("#employerCont")
    $incCont = $("#incCont")

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        Calculate();
    })
    $("#submit2").click(function() {
        Calculate2();
    })

});

function Calculate() {



    document.getElementById('pensionRev').style.display = "block";
    var pension = $($pension_cont).val()
    var employee = $($employerCont).val()

    var totalpension =  parseFloat(pension) + parseFloat(employee);
    var pensionfinal = ($($salary).val() / 100) * totalpension * (($($ret_age).val()) - $($DOB).val())

    $('#pensionfinal').html(pensionfinal);

}



function Calculate2() {

    document.getElementById('pensionRev2').style.display = "block";
    var pension = $($pension_cont).val();
    var employee = $($employerCont).val();
    var totalpension =  parseFloat(pension) + parseFloat(employee);
    var agesort = $($ret_age).val() - $($DOB).val();
    var totalincrease = ($($incCont).val() * 12) * agesort;
    var pensionfinal = ($($salary).val() / 100) * totalpension * agesort;
    var pensionfinal2 = pensionfinal + totalincrease;
    var increase = totalincrease



    $('#pensionfinal2').html(pensionfinal2);
    $('#increase').html(totalincrease);

}
```

I would like the select to allow the user to select between pounds/integer and percentage to change the output of pensionfinal2 depending on what the user has chosen. Also if you could add comments to show me what each part of the code is doing that would be much appreciated.

edit: Sorry it's hard to explain, this is a pension calculator and after it goes through the first calculation and shows you the final number it gives you the option to add a certain amount of pounds each month and it then again calculates what your pension would be after adding the addition funds per month but I would like the user to have the option to select whether they want to add £5 or 5% which I've started with the select tag with the name "operate"

Comment: can you create a problem **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)**

Comment: What is the problem ? Explain your problem and also explain that what do you want to do?

Comment: It seems like you are almost there so agree with the other comments that you need to make a more specific question(s)
But without coding anything depending on your mode percent or pound you will run a different calculation - so you can do it in a single function the use a simple if statement to calculate and return the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this code will help you or not cause the code that you shared is incomplete but still I have noticed few mistakes in your Javascript code

Check following code which is a valid version of your code

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="pensionRev"  style="margin: 0 auto; width:600px;" class="answer_list" >
    <h3><u>Your pension will come to &pound;<span id="pensionfinal"></span></u></h3>
    <h3>If you contribute an additional
        <select name="operate" style="width:59px; text-align:left; font-size:17px;">
            <option value="pound" id="percentage">&pound;</option>
            <option value="percentage" id="percentage">%</option>
        </select>
        <div class="inpt" id="smallnum">
            <input class="input-xxsmall" id="incCont"
                   name="incCont" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="?">
        </div>
        a month
    </h3>
    <h3>Your pot will be.....
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Submit" type="submit">

    </div>

</div>
<div id="pensionRev2" style="display:none;margin: 0 auto;  width:600px; border-radius:20px; border-bottom:ridge black 5px;" class="answer_list" >
    <h2 style="text-decoration:underline;">&pound;<span id="pensionfinal2"></span>!</h2>
    This is an increase of &pound;<span id="increase"></span></h3>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var salary = '#salary';
var eepension = '#eecontrib';
var pension_cont = '#pension_cont';
var ret_age = '#ret_age';
var DOB = '#DOB';
var employerCont = '#employerCont';
var incCont = '#incCont';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        Calculate();
    })
    $("#submit2").click(function() {
        Calculate2();
    })

});
function Calculate() {
    document.getElementById('pensionRev').style.display = "block";
    var pension = $(pension_cont).val()
    var employee = $(employerCont).val()

    var totalpension =  parseFloat(pension) + parseFloat(employee);
    var pensionfinal = ($(salary).val() / 100) * totalpension * (($(ret_age).val()) - $(DOB).val())
    $('#pensionfinal').html(pensionfinal);
}



function Calculate2() {
    document.getElementById('pensionRev2').style.display = "block";
    var pension = $(pension_cont).val();
    var employee = $(employerCont).val();
    var totalpension =  parseFloat(pension) + parseFloat(employee);
    var agesort = $(ret_age).val() - $(DOB).val();
    var totalincrease = ($(incCont).val() * 12) * agesort;
    var pensionfinal = ($(salary).val() / 100) * totalpension * agesort;
    var pensionfinal2 = pensionfinal + totalincrease;
    var increase = totalincrease;
    $('#pensionfinal2').html(pensionfinal2);
    $('#increase').html(totalincrease);

}
</script>
```

The above code is valid Javascript Code

Problem in your code
you are creating variables with `$` but in javascript you declare variables with `var`
you assigned variables to elements in wrong way
Eg.

```
 $salary = $("#salary");
```

and in code you are using it in this way

```
$($salary) === $($("#salary"))
```

which is wrong

checkout this simple code

```
    <input class="input-xxsmall" id="incCont" name="incCont" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="?">
<input type="button" id="simple-button" value="Click Here"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var element = "#incCont";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#simple-button").click(function(){
            alert($(element).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

here I have declared element with

```
var element = "#incCont"
```

and I am using it in this way

```
$(element).val() === $("#incCont").val()
```

Hope this will help you
Happy to help :)

Comment: Yeah man it works! Was wondering do you know how I could set it up so that the other divs fade in?

Comment: instead of using document.getElementById('pensionRev2').style.display = "block"; simply use .fadeIn() or fadeToggle() in jquery eg. $("#pensionRev2").fadeIn();  @JamieBrown